# Connect Python to kafka on AWS EC2 from local machine

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to connect my python application to kafka running on AWS EC2. I am able to connect with ec2 via terminal i check with `telnet <ec2 ip> 9092`. I am able to connect via this but not able to connect with python application. 
Even if my python application starts with without any error with ec2 ip address, i am not able to receive any data from my kafka topic from ec2 to local machine.

When i add my pulic ip address to:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<local ip addrss>:9092
```

Debezium connector with kafka-connect won't start  , but without enabling advertised.listeners it works.

How do i configure kafka and kafka-connect so that i can consume kafka topic from ec2 instance on my local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `advertised.listeners` to be the EC2 Public DNS/IP, restart the broker, then open the VPC / firewall connection on the listening port.

Debezium's `rest.advertised.listener` property is different from Kafka broker's, and you woudn't need it set on your local machine.

Python and Kafka Connect should share the same `bootstrap.server` protocol

You can test your listeners better using `kafkacat -L -b <bootstrap>:9092`